# Limit resources (cpu/mem) only in ssh session

Tags: ssh, cgroups

I have a server with 4 GPUs/128 cores where I use a workload manager (slurm) to manage resource allocation between users for computation.

The issue is that the scheduler server (for job submission) runs on the same machine<sup>(1)</sup>, where users connect through ssh to submit jobs.

I would like to restrict the resource allocation (cpu/mem) for all users **only inside their ssh session**, so that they will not run heavy computations outside the scheduling system (but they can inside jobs).

I know I can use cgroups to implement such limit, e.g.:

```bsh
cgcreate -g memory,cpu:cpulimited
cgset -r cpu.shares=100 cpulimited # limit to ~10% of cpu use
cgset -r memory.limit_in_bytes=$((10*1024*1024*1024)) # limit to 10 GB
```

How can I ensure that any ssh session will be run in this cgroup `cpulimited`? but in the same time, when slurm lauches a job, I don't want to bypass the limit set by the scheduler (for any user).

(1) I need a workload manager because I have several users and it can be chaotic without it, however I don't have any other machine that could be the scheduling server (like on any standard cluster).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem so I share it.

I defined a cgroup `customssh/limit` using the `cgconfig` service from the libcgroup. Here is an extract of my `cgconfig.conf` file:

```
group customssh/limit {
  perm {
    admin {
      uid=root;
      gid=root;
    }
    task {
      uid=myuser;
      gid=mygroup;
      fperm=775;
    }
  }
  cpu {
    cpu.shares=50;
  }
  memory {
    memory.limit_in_bytes="10G";
    memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes="10G";
    memory.soft_limit_in_bytes="2G";
  }
  devices {
    devices.deny="c 195:* rwm";
  }
}
```

- `fperm = 775` allows users of the group `mygroup` to use this cgroup
- I enforce limit on CPU and memory usage, and deny access to GPUs with `devices.deny="c 195:* rwm";`

I created the file `/etc/profile.d/ssh.sh` which is run on every login with the following contents:

```bsh
# check if the user is in a ssh session
if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
    # shell PID 
    SESSIONPID=$$
    # attach the shell to the `customssh/limit` cgroup
    cgclassify -g memory,cpu,devices:customssh/limit $SESSIONPID
    # all processes run by this shell will be affected
fi
```